# Reliability of the scale

Tags: reliability, consistency

Do we have to calculate  Cronbach's alpha for all the questions ( items) or just the variables? I have 7 variables: 4 independent, 1 dependent, 1 mediating, and 1 moderating, and 23  items  23.

Should calculate the alpha value for 23 items or 7 variables ?

Answer (score 1):

You usually calculate alpha for scales that you plan to use. I don't understand your use of the term variable, because if your items are not variables, you (usually) can't calculate alpha.

Say I want to know the correlation between extroversion and intelligence. I might have 10 questions on extroversion (things like "I enjoy parties with lots of people.") I would usually calculate the alpha of the extroversion scale, with these 10 items (which are variables). Then I might calculate a mean or a total of these scores, and create a variable called extroversion.

Then I have 10 intelligence questions (What is 24 * 16?). Again, I have 10 items, I calculate the alpha for the 10 items, and then calculate an intelligence score (and that will be a variable).

Finally, I estimate the correlation between those two scores - of extroversion and intelligence (and they are both variables too).